# (XDK app framework java script) how to check if a animated sidebar is completely opened?

Tags: javascript, sidebar, intel-xdk, appframework

I am kinda new to XDK and java script (a C# coder), and I am having a hard time trying to figure out how I can check if an animated side bar is completely opened, I am using App framework in Intel XDK tool ( i think I am trying to find js/sidebar.js API reference ). here is how I call the sidebar to open, close or toggle :

```
uib_sb.open_sidebar($sb)

uib_sb.close_sidebar($sb)

uib_sb.toggle_sidebar($sb)
```

but what I need is to check is completely open so activate or deactivate buttons.

by the way can you call functions with timed delay (e.g. have a button to call a function after 2 seconds)

and finally (How) can you have a regular Java script update function in HTML 5 (yep Im giving away my intentions to program a game like app)

Comment: what have you tried so far? Can you show us a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something?

Comment: so far I haven't had any luck tracking the sidebar animation or position (while it slides from outside in). I did try to convert couple of .net tricks to figure out this sidebar object but I must admit that either app framework API is too complicated for me or it just doesn't give you full control over your objects. either way where is the API documentation?

Comment: I'm not clear on why you need to activate or deactivate buttons based on the position of the sidebar.  Are you talking about butons on the sidebar?  Or buttons elsewhere?  Why would you want to deactivate them in any case?

Comment: lets say I have a button that toggles the sidebar now while the sidebar is animating (moving) you can click the button again very fast (like a double click) to reopen the sidebar while is not fully closed (half way closed and it will open again) , now in some cases I may not want that so it would be helpful to know when the side bar is fully opened or closed to activate or deactivate the toggle button. so far the only trick I can think of is to delay the activity of the button after each click thanks to your answer down below. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about how to tell when an AppFramework sidebar is completely opened, but if there is a way to tell that, it would likely be either through an event or callback function.

Setting a delay is easy in javascirpt, simply use `setTimeout`.  For example to throw an alert after 2 seconds you could do something like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {alert('delayed response');}, 2000)
```

As far as an "update function", there are at least two possibilities.  To cause something to be run at regular intervals, you can use `setInterval` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval for details).  If you're primarily interested in updating the animation at each frame, then you'll probably want to use `requestAnimationFrame`, described here - http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/efficient-animations-with-requestanimationframe